# How dangerous is "Free blocks count wrong"?

Tags: filesystems, block-device, fsck, corruption

I ran `fsck` in read-only mode and got some errors like this :

```
Free blocks count wrong (5597728, counted=5231480).
Fix? no
```

As stated [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/817-5093/fstroublefsck-51788.html) :

> **Free Block Checks**
>
> Free blocks are stored in the cylinder group block maps. The fsck command checks that all the blocks marked as free are not claimed by any files. When all the blocks have been accounted for, the fsck command checks if the number of free blocks plus the number of blocks that are claimed by the inodes equal the total number of blocks in the file system. If anything is wrong with the block maps, the fsck command rebuilds them, leaving out blocks already allocated

In this situation is it possible that for example when a file grows , some blocks of other files get overwritten?